# PHP Variable Empty Outside Foreach?

Tags: php

I have a class system and a function inside it that does a foreach from DB results. The variable is assigned inside the foreach, but outside of the foreach it is empty.

```
// Top of file
private $movieList = array();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                // add each to the array
                $this->movieList[] = array('nid' => $row->nid, 'title' => $row->title, 'movie_pos_id' => $row->movie_pos_id);
                print_r($this->movieList); // variable full of stuff
            }
            // No results found
            return false;
        }

print_r($this->movieList); // variable empty
```

Any idea why?

Comment: can you post the entire code; my bet is that you're printing it before the loop actually runs

Comment: It was not that `$query->num_rows() > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like your line outside the if statement would never execute because you always return false if you got results. Check your brackets. You probably mean this:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        // add each to the array
        $this->movieList[] = 
            array('nid' => $row->nid, 'title' => $row->title, 
                'movie_pos_id' => $row->movie_pos_id);
        print_r($this->movieList); // variable full of stuff
    }
}
else {
    // No results found
    return false;
}

print_r($this->movieList);
```

Comment: LOL I can't believe that... lol Thanks, I need to stop coding at night.

Answer (score 1):

Your braces are mismatched. Try this

```
// Top of file
private $movieList = array();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                // add each to the array
                $this->movieList[] = array('nid' => $row->nid, 'title' => $row->title, 'movie_pos_id' => $row->movie_pos_id);
                print_r($this->movieList); // variable full of stuff
            }
}else{
            // No results found
            return false;
}


print_r($this->movieList); // variable empty
```